Part of VSCode window in full screen is unclickable
I have a pretty fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04. When I maximaze a vscode window, most of it becomes unclickable. If I place another window behind vscode and click on the unclickable part the window behind gets focus.
I've found this issue at vscode's github and I've copied what has been suggested here
This is what I have in /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
#Exec=/usr/share/code/code %F
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform,WaylandWindowDecorations --ozone-platform-hint=auto %F

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
#Exec=/usr/share/code/code --new-window %F
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform,WaylandWindowDecorations --ozone-platform-hint=auto --new-window %F

This is what I have in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=nikita

# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
# WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true

So far the only workaround I found is to call sudo systemctl restart gdm3 every time the system loads. After I call that, the issues goes away. Is there a way to permanently fix this issue?
